# Связи в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется метод контроллера, выводящий посты по заданным условиям. К каждому посту может быть привязано несколько покупок, в модели покупки сортируются по id и в view выводится последняя из них

Модель **Posts** :

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user(){
       $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'post_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
}
```

и модель **Purchases**

```
class Purchase extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts','id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Модель **Purchases** имеет поле user_id, то есть id пользователя, совершившего покупку. Мне необходимо передать данные, о купившем пользователе во вьюху, через данную функцию контроллера:

```
 public function sold(){
        $post=Posts::where([
            ['amount', '=', 0],
            ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
        ])->with('purchases')->paginate(5);


        return view('SoldItems')->withPost($post);
    }
```

Как мне это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели **Posts** попробуй прописать вот так

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user(){
       $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'post_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with("user");
    }
}
```